# How event subscriptions in Event Hub Namespace work?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I might be confused about concepts but I have Azure Activity Logs exported to Azure Event Hub which works as expected. Event Hub `insights-operational-logs` is created and I see events posted there. I created event subscription as well but it does not show any events coming at all. What am I missing?
Exact steps.

1. Go to Azure Activity Log and export it to Event Hub of my choice.
2. Go to eventhub namespace and click on "Events" and choose "+ Event
   Subscription".
3. Specify capture all events and specify endpoint as Storage Queue

[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly with *I created event subscription*?

Comment: Updated question with steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the term event subscription, you mean that you have created an event grid subscription to your Event Hub namespace.

> So whenever an event is sent to the Event Hub within the Event Hub Namespace, the event will be captured and stored in the blob storage configured provided you have enabled capture while creating the event hub. On successful capture of the event, an event will be sent by the Event Subscription to the configured endpoint(in your case ,the storage queue) which will have the captured blob url.

You can find the events in the storage queue configured.

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-grid-event-hubs-integration) for for more details on Event Hub - Event Grid integration

Comment: So without capture enabled this subscription will never fire?

Comment: Yes @Gregory Suvalian